# How to get instance of service from a view that is held in service?

Tags: android

I have a service that I use to display a custom view via `WindowManager` and keep it on screen for a while. Is it possible to get an instance of my service from within my custom view? I think it should because I'm basically holding a reference to that view in my service like below:

```
MyCustomView mCustomView;
...

onCreate() {
   mCustomView = new MyCustomView(this);
   ...
}
```

Comment: you are passing the service's instance to the constructor ... what is stopping you from using it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service acts as the context for your custom view. And `View` class has a `getContext()` method which, obviously, returns context provided earlier. You just need to cast your context to your service:

```
MyService service = (MyService)mCustomView.getContext();
```

Comment: Huh didn't think it could do that. Great. But can it cause some memory leak or can it inscrease the RAM usage if I keep this reference? I'm not declaring it globally, just using it in a method called from the same service (lol I just realized I could have just passed the reference in the method constructor).

Comment: As long as you don't store that context outside of normal service lifecycle (as a static variable for instance), you are fine

Comment: But view will be leaked if will be destroyed and service still running..

Comment: @Selvin if view is destroyed - it is not a problem. The problem will be if you keep a reference to this view after it was destroyed. And from the original question, it doesn't seem like OP holds a reference to view. OP wants a reference to hosting Service (which is not a problem)

Comment: @Selvin @Pavel Dudka I'm only holding a reference to the view in the service `MyCustomView mCustomView;` and nowhere else. So if the service is terminated the view will be destroyed as well. And I'm neither holding the view as static or destroying the view while the service is running.

Answer (score 1):

While I have not tried it, I would assume that `getContext()` on your `View` would return your `Service`, assuming your `Service` is the `this` in your code snippet in your question.

Comment: hmmm what about fx: public AppCompatTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super( **TintContextWrapper.wrap(context)** , attrs, defStyleAttr);`

Comment: do you ever sleep at all? :) sometimes it feels like you visit every single Android related SO post!

Comment: Hey it's @CommonsWare. Dude you're amazing.

Comment: @Selvin: I do not know if you can use `appcompat-v7` classes outside of an `AppCompatActivity`. Regardless, you are correct that there could be a `ContextWrapper` involved. However, unlike with activities, I do not know of any situation where a `ContextWrapper` would be applied behind your back with a service. That's why I couched my answer with "assuming your `Service` is the `this` in your code snippet". If you intentionally apply your own `ContextWrapper`, that's fine, but then you will need to unwrap it to get at the `Service` instance.

Comment: It was just an example that assumption is not enough.